# PHP Login Validation Message Displaying when Password is Correct

Tags: php, validation, authentication, password-hash

I have created a login page for my website using PHP. For the validation, I would like error messages to display if the username doesn't exist, if the password is wrong or if the user hasn't entered one or the other. Most of my validation works except validating if the password is correct. The code I used is below. I believe the problem is with the password_verify if statement. The error message prompting the user that the password is incorrect is appearing even when the password is correct.

```
<?php
// Initalise session
session_start();

//Check if the user is already logged in, if yes then redirect to members page
if(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] === true){
header("location: members.php");
exit;
}

//Include config file
require_once "config.php";

//Define variables and initalise with empty values
$username = $password = "";
$username_err = $password_err = "";

//Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

   //Check if username is empty
   if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
      $username_err = "Please enter your username.";
   } else{
      $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
   }

   //Check if password is empty
   if(empty(trim($_POST["password"]))){
      $password_err = "Please enter your password.";
   } else{
      $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
   }

//Validate credentials
if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err)){
    //Prepare a select statement
    $sql = "SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username = ?";

    if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)){
        //Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $param_username);

        //Set parameters
        $param_username = $username;

        //Attempt to execute the prepared statement
        if($stmt->execute()){
            //Store result
            $stmt->store_result();

            //Check if username exists, if yes then verify password
            if($stmt->num_rows == 1){
                //Bind result variables
                $stmt->bind_result($username, $password);

                if($stmt->fetch()){
                    if(password_verify($password, $_POST['password'])){
                        //Password is correct, so start a new session
                        session_start();

                        //Store data in session variables
                        $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
                        $_SESSION["username"] = $username;

                        //Redirect user to members page
                        header("location: members.php");
                    } else {
                        //Display an error message if password is not valid
                        $password_err = "The password you entered was not valid.";
                    }
                }
            } else{
                //Display an error message if username doesn't exist
                $username_err = "No account found with that username.";
            }
        } else{
            echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
        }

        //Close statement
        $stmt->close();
    }
}

//Close connection
$mysqli->close();
}
 ?>
```

Comment: make sure the column storing the password is atleast varchar(60). And make sure you are entering the right password (just in case)

Comment: Show how you hashed the password

Answer (score 1):

You have your variables [flip-flopped](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php):

```
if(password_verify($password, $_POST['password'])){
```

should be

```
if(password_verify($_POST['password'], $password)){
```

**NOTES**

It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527) or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

[Password hashes in PHP are at least 60 characters long](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html), make sure the column where you're storing the password is larger in order to handle future hashing algorithms. `VARCHAR(255)` or `TEXT` have enough storage to accommodate future hashes.